# Replace all characters except the first four characters

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I want to pipe in a command to sed like so:

```
md5sum input.txt | sed 's/^\(....\).*/\1/;q'
```

This works by only outputting the first 4 characters of the checksum. However, I want to output the first 4 characters, but also have an x in the place of every other characters (redacting info). I'm so lost now.

Comment: If the filename contains conflicting characters (like a newline) the output of `md5sum` starts with a backslash ```\```. I shall assume that such starting (optional) character should be allowed, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU Sed,

```
md5sum input.txt | sed 's/./x/5g'
```

This simply skips substituting the 4 first characters of the string and performs the substitution for all other characters.

A POSIX alternative with Awk (although there is probably something simpler),

```
md5sum xad | awk '{
  four=substr($0, 1, 4)
  rest=substr($0, 5)
  gsub(/./, "x", rest)
  print four, rest
}' OFS=""
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make it recursive solely using the .sed script. Is that possible?

Comment: New questions should be posted as their own questions...

Comment: Nice try, but: Note that the sed  command will change also the spaces and the file name to x's. Not only the 128 bit file hash.

Comment: @Isaac Sure, I'm answering to the question, which reads "Replace **all characters except the first four** characters". You are thinking of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615942

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly (I think), you could use a sed loop to repeatedly replace the first non-`x` character following the 4-character prefix:

```
$ md5sum input.txt | sed '
:a
s/^\(....x*\)[^x]/\1x/
ta
'
```

Replace `[^x]` with `[^x ]` if you only want to do the substitution in the first field (the checksum).

Answer (score 4):

With `perl` if `GNU sed` isn't available:

```bsh
md5sum input.txt | perl -pe 's/^.{4}(*SKIP)(*F)|./x/g'
```

`^.{4}(*SKIP)(*F)` will prevent replacement of first four characters

`|.` specifies the alternate pattern that has to be replaced

To change only the checksum:

```bsh
md5sum ip.txt | perl -pe 's/(^.{4}|\h.*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|./x/g'
```

If the `md5sum` output starts with a `\` (for ex: if filename has a newline character), then you can use `^\\?.{4}` instead of `^.{4}` to allow first five characters to be left unmasked.

Answer (score 3):

Another `perl` variant to replace all but the first 4 bytes of the checksum (and the checksum only) with `x`:

```
$ md5sum input.txt | perl -pe 's{.{4}\K\S+}{$& =~ s/./x/gr}e'
d632xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  input.txt
```

Comment: This answers exactly [Replace each characters until specifc character seen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615942). Consider putting this answer there.

Comment: I shall assume that an optional starting backslash ```\``` (for filenames with conflicting characters (like a newline)) should be allowed. So, maybe: `'s{\\?.{4}\K\S+}{$& =~ s/./x/gr}e'` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Quasímodo's answer is that it also replaces the filename with `x`'s.  OP posted a followup question about that.  Here's a `sed` solution that stops at the space:

`md5sum` always produces a 32-character output for the hash.  Instead of detecting a space, you could look for 32-characters then a space and replace the last 28 characters with an X.

```
md5sum input.txt | sed 's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /g'
35c9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  input.txt
```

Breaking down the statement:

```
's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /g'

's/ A                                     / B                             /g'
we're substituting patterns matching A with B globally

's/   [a-zA-Z0-9]       [a-zA-Z0-9]       /                               /g'
we're looking for two groups of alphanumeric  characters

's/   [a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}  [a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /                               /g'
The first group has exactly four characters
The second group has exactly twenty-eight characters

's/ \([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /                               /g'
The first group is a "capture group" which we can reference later

's/ \([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /\1                             /g'
We will print out the first group verbatim in the output

's/ \([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /g'
We will print x's followed by a space for the next 28 characters

's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\}\)[a-zA-Z0-9]\{28\} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /g'
The statement must appear at the start of a line and have a space at the end.
```

Comment: (1) An **```s```** command that is anchored by `^` or `$` cannot work more than once per line, so specifying the `g` option is pointless and potentially confusing.  (2) As long as you’re sure what the input looks like, you could use `\(.\{4\}\).\{28\} ` (or even `\(....\).\{28\} `) as your *from* pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The MD5 hash is always 32 characters long. The first four characters may be had by cutting with `cut -c -4`, and the 28 `x` required to pad out the rest of the hash may be added with `printf`:

```
$ md5sum somefile
d68610fdffd770de94818268899d6abb  somefile
$ printf '%sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n' $(md5sum somefile | cut -c -4)
d686xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You may also use `%.4s` instead of `%s` in the `printf` format string to get rid of the `cut`:

```
$ printf '%.4sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n' "$(md5sum somefile)"
d686xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

... although this would only work for formatting the hashes of a single file at a time.

Comment: The initial word is not always 32 characters long. If the filename requires encoding (like a file name with a newline), the first word starts with a ```\```. Try `echo 'a test' >$'file\nname' ; md5sum $'file\nname'`

Answer (score 0):

With standard POSIX sed you can do it, although it's more complicated:

```
md5sum input.txt | sed -E 'h;s/^(.{4}).*$/\1/;x;s/^.{4}(.*)$/\1/;s/./x/g;H;x;s/\n//'
```

Here is what the sed script does:

```
h                   copy the pattern buffer into the hold buffer
s/^(.{4}).*$/\1/    keep just the first four characters in the pattern buffer
x                   exchange the pattern buffer with the hold buffer
s/^.{4}(.*)$/\1/    keep all but the first four characters in the pattern buffer
s/./x/g             replace each character with an x
H                   append newline and x's to hold buffer (which has the first four)
x                   exchange again; the pattern buffer has an extra newline, though
s/\n//              remove the newline from the pattern buffer
```

The pattern buffer now has the first four characters plus x's for all the remaining characters; the cycle ends, and it is printed out.

Note: the -E switch enables extended regex syntax. It isn't strictly necessary here; instead, a backslash could be placed before each open and close parenthesis, but I think it's hard enough to read without extra backslashes in it.

Comment: Nice try, but: Note that this command will change also the spaces and the file name to `x`'s. Not only the 128 bit file hash.

Comment: @Isaac So will the accepted answer. As will the method in the question.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer suffers of the same issue, but I haven't got around to comment it. In any case, the note from my command would be useful to everyone, IMO.