# Replace all characters until specific character seen

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

For example, this is the md5sum command outputs:

```
35c9581c469c366e286be708a9d9f939  input.txt
```

This is the command line I'm running:

```
md5sum input.txt | sed -f script.sed
```

I want to make the output of md5sum look like this:

```
35c9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  input.txt
```

Currently, my .sed script contains this, which redacts everything except the first 4 chars:

```
s/./x/5g
```

I need to get it to stop doing this when it sees the space " ". Any thoughts?

Comment: I just noticed this question is a follow-up of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615928/sed-regex-question.  It'd probably be better to respond to the problems in the answer you got there.  I'll add my answer there.

Comment: @Stewart I think that actually the best is what OP has done, namely to ask another question instead of changing the meaning of a question after it has already been answered, as that would require existing answers to sync with each modification.

Answer (score 5):

If (md5sum) hashes; then this would do the job (in a shell that supports brace-expansion)

```
sed -e's/./x/'{5..32} infile
```

---

else for any character length until first character space seen; then:

Using `sed`, and as a general solution:

```
sed -E ':a s/^(.{4}x{0,})[^x ]/\1x/;ta' infile
```

- `:a` is a *sed* label we named `a`
- `s/` substitute below matches

  - `^` is start of line anchor
  - `(` opens a group match

    - `.` matches a single character
    - `.{4}` matches 4 characters (or just `....`) followed by
    - `x{0,}` 0-or-more `x` characters (or `x*`)
  - `)` end of group match and back-reference is `\1`
  - `[^x ]` matches any character except characters `x`,  (in character class the `^` negate the match if it's first character immediately after open `[` in `[^...]`);
- `/` with below

  - `\1` was back-reference to parts matched above within `(...)`, so we return back the first part again to its place but evetime extra `x`s added into it.
  - then a `x`; remember at above we didn't capture `[^x ]` within a group-match `(...)`? these are the characters we are replacing them with `x` now one by one.
- `/` end of substitution
- `;` start a new command
- `ta` jump to label `a` if substitution was successful; if not, means we replaced all characters into `x` and now none left to replace and end the `sed` command.

Comment: in `fish`, you can do `sed -e's/./x/'(seq 5 32) infile`

Answer (score 4):

`md5sum` always produces a 32-character output for the hash.  Instead of detecting a space, you could look for 32-characters then a space and replace the last 28 characters with an X.

```
md5sum input.txt | sed -E 's/^([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /'
35c9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  input.txt
```

Breaking down the statement:

```
's/^([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /'

's/A                                  / B                             /'
we're substituting patterns matching A with B

's/  [[:xdigit:]]    [[:xdigit:]]     /                               /'
we're looking for two groups of hexadecimal characters

's/  [[:xdigit:]]{4} [[:xdigit:]]{28} /                               /'
The first group has exactly four characters
The second group has exactly twenty-eight characters

's/ ([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /                               /'
The first group is a "capture group" which we can reference later

's/ ([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /\1                             /'
We will print out the first group verbatim in the output

's/ ([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /'
We will print x's followed by a space for the next 28 characters

's/^([[:xdigit:]]{4})[[:xdigit:]]{28} /\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /'
The statement must appear at the start of a line and have a space at the end.
```

Comment: A hexadecimal digit may also be matched by `[[:xdigit:]]`, which may be easier to read and also shows the intent of the developer.

Comment: You're right.  I changed `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[[:xdigit:]]`.  Filtering hex-digits instead of alphanumeric characters is a good idea.   Also `[a-zA-Z0-9]` works for the C locale, but may not work well for other locales in defining alphanumeric characters.

Comment: About all those backslashes, according to GNU's `sed` manpage, `-E` is a POSIX portable option to enable extended regexp.

Comment: Very good point.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

A Perl approach:

```
$ md5sum file | perl -ple 's/^(.{4})(\S+)(\s+.*)/$1 . "x" x length($2) . $3/e'
9191xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  file
```

That will find the first 4 characters (`^(.{4})`), then as many non-whitespace characters as possible (`(\S+)`) and then the first one or more spaces followed by anything until the end of the line (`(\s+.*)`). That is then replaced by the first captured value (`$1`, the 1st 4 characters), the string `x` repeated as many times as the length of the second captured group (`"x" x length($2)`) and then the final captured group, `$3`. The `/e` at the end of the substitution operator is needed to allow us to evaluate commands inside the `s///`.

Of course, if you know you'll always be running `md5sum`, so the length of the hash - 4 will always be 28, you could simplify to:

```
$ md5sum file | perl -ple 's/^(.{4})(\S+)/$1 . "x" x 28/e'
9191xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  file
```

Or even:

```
$ md5sum file | perl -ple 's/(?<=.{4})(\S+)/"x" x 28/e'
9191xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ md5sum somefile
d68610fdffd770de94818268899d6abb  somefile
```

```
$ md5sum somefile | { read -r hash pathname; printf '%.4sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  %s\n' "$hash" "$pathname" }
d686xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  somefile
```

This reads the hash and the pathname into two shell variables and then prints these out with the 28 last characters of the hash replaced by `x`.

To support multiple files, use a loop:

```
$ md5sum somefile* | while read -r hash pathname; do printf '%.4sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  %s\n' "$hash" "$pathname"; done
d41dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  somefile
d686xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  somefile1
d41dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  somefile2
```