# "Invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS" error for sed script

Tags: text-processing, sed

For example, this is the md5sum command outputs:

```
35c9581c469c366e286be708a9d9f939 input.txt
```

This is the command line I'm running:

```
md5sum input.txt | sed -f script.sed
```

I want to make the output of md5sum look like this:

```
35c9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx input.txt
```

Currently, my .sed script contains this:

```
:a s/^(.{4}x{0,})[^x ]/\1x/;ta
```

I keep getting this error

```
sed: file script.sed line 2: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

and I'm not sure why. If anyone knows how to fix it, or even a better way, please let me know.

Comment: -1 that sed command in your question already contains `-E`  you taken it from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615960/72456, don't you know that you can comment under the answers you received for your questions? and sounds you have more than one account!

Comment: Yeah apparently I was a guest when I posted the last one, so I had to start from scratch with this verified account

Comment: Nah it's ok you don't have to worry! Now that I have an actual account, I'll just forget about the question from the guest account and ask from this account going forward

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help on merging your accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either use extended regex with `sed -E` if available **or** escape the braces and parenthesis:

```
:a s/^\(.\{4\}x\{0,\}\)[^x ]/\1x/;ta
```